# How to search for resources by tag on IBM Cloud via REST API?

Tags: api, ibm-cloud

We can add tags to resources, but how do we search by tags?

To create and list we can use https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/resource-controller

but can’t seems to find filtering by tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [Search API](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/search#find-instances-of-resources-204a87). See the [CLI documentation for the search syntax](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/resources?topic=resources-searching-for-resources#searching-cl) based on Lucene. You would search for the attribute **tags** like `tags:MyTag`.